# web crawler to generate output cache

Tags: asp.net, outputcache

I implemented :

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="43200" VaryByParam="none" location="Server" VaryByCustom="RawURL" %>
```

I have got a sitemap.xml with all url(about 12000) possible in my site.

**I would know if it's judicious to create an application that will parse my sitemap in
order to request all url?**

The Goal is caching all my web site to increase velocity.

**I precise my question :**

Each page take about 10 sec to be created and the cache duration and cache duration is 12 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the time to dynamically create any one individual page relatively fast, then you probably would not be gaining much by doing this.

Probably you are better just leaving the output cache at a modest time limit (5 - 15 minutes) to avoid using a lot of ram,  and also  to keep the pages fresh (unless you have a good way of expiring the output cache each time a page is updated).  If a page is popular enough to be accessed frequently, it will most likely be cached when a person goes to it.

Comment: ok I edited my question the time to dynamically create any one individual page is not fast at all it's why I need to cache them.

Comment: Well in that case then probably it is worth at least testing.  I don't see any downsides other than the increased ram usage.  In the latest version of .net you can create ouput cache providers so if memory is a concern you could get one that will use file based storage.  http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/11/19/asp-net-4-0-writing-custom-output-cache-providers.aspx